# How to write a Regular expression for only 1 letter followed by a fullstop?

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex which captures a single letter followed by a fullstop but if it is in a word it should not cature that. for eg: in the sentence "This is Dr. Mathurs cabin." - it should only capture 'r.' from Dr. and not 'n.', as it is a complete word. Capture only words which have a single letter or at the max 2 letters in them. I tried this regex:

```
expr = ('[a-zA-Z]\.')
line = re.sub(expr, '', line)
```

This results in 'r.' and also 'n.' being replaced, which I dont want. How can we restrict it to check if there is a single letter before fullstop or at the maximum 2.

Comment: What about: `Yes it is.`? Must the last `s` be captured?

Comment: In this case , it should be captured, if we limit the capturing to 2 letters before fullstop. If we limit it to a single digit, it should not be captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
(?i)(?<![a-z]{2})[a-z]\.
```

It matches a letter followed by a dot only when there are not 2 letters before.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/LJ83pN/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this too

```
\b.{0,1}(.\.)
```

### Explanation

`\b` searches for a pattern at the beginning or end of the word

---

`.{0,1}` matches any character with 0 or 1 repetitions

---

`(.\.)` where `()` is for capture group `.` matches any single character and `\.` to escape the actual period

You can find the detailed explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/K1KhPK/1) with examples